# mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php, mysql, warnings

```
require("includes/connect.php");

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries", $link);

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                htmlentities($row['quotes']);
            }
```

I am trying to display data that is in the database, but I keep on getting:

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string
```

Is there anything wrong in the above code that is causing the problem? I am quite new to PHP and I am trying to understand what's going on and why it's doing it.

connect.php

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

    if (!$link) {
        die("Could not connect to the db");
    }

    mysql_select_db("ENTRIES",  $link);
```

(I'm working on this locally, so user/pass really isn't important right now)

Comment: It's not the code above that's causing the problem, since there is no `mysql_real_escape_string()` in it. Unless it's in included `connect.php` file, in which case we'd need to see it.

Comment: Post the code from your `connect.php` file.

Comment: Done, and I have tried to use mysql_real_escape_string() but I was doing it wrong. How can I properly place that in?

Comment: You need to post the code were you use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: @Trippy Where *do* you actually use `mysql_real_escape_string` that causes this warning?

Comment: ^ I currently don't use that. But when I did attempt to I placed it $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries", $link); so, yeah, I have no idea what I'm doing(kinda). I'm really trying to learn though.

Comment: @Tippy, you must be using it, otherwise you wouldn't be getting the error. Do you mean you took it out because you were getting the error? If so, show us what the code was like before then we can say why it was wrong.

Comment: No, I took it out because when I attempted to do it, it gave me an error. before this error. But when I did attempt it, I did this:

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries"), mysql_real_escape_string($link));

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point with escaping the above query, but you could do it like this:

```
 $result = mysql_query(mysql_real_escape_string("SELECT * FROM entries"), $link);
```

You should read the documentation: [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Then you are using `mysql_real_escape_string()` somewhere else, It's a bit hard to give you any advice because you haven't posted the relevant code.

Comment: All of the PHP I am using is up there.

Comment: And were is your call to `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

Comment: I saw in your comment that your were doing `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries"), mysql_real_escape_string($link));` the correct way to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` is in my code above, so why the downvote?

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, trying to understand.

Comment: You're using it somewhere else and you haven't posted the code where you do. There is no other reason.

Comment: I didn`t downvote, but, I think, the reason is that `mysql_real_escape_string` is used to escape user input, not the whole query. If used on whole query, it will lead to unpredictable results. Furthemore, simple query like `SELECT * FROM entries` has no need to be escaped somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, I did a typo somewhere else after pasting, it worked.

Comment: @Timur - Like I say in the answer - "I don't see the point"=)

Answer (score 0):

As the error explains `mysql_real_escape_string()` takes a string as a parameter. In your code you posted as a comment you are passing `$link` which isn't a string, it's a database connection.

As @kristen, has said to solution should be to wrap you sql statement like so

```
$result = mysql_query(mysql_real_escape_string("SELECT * FROM entries"), $link);
```

If you are still receiving the error after this, you must be using the function elsewhere.